# POST textarea data using Requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm learning using Requests and I have a problem with posting and retrieving data from Textarea field from a form.

```
import requests

url = 'https://northcutt.com/tools/free-seo-tools/multiple-reverse-ip-lookup/'
values = {'f_ip_list' : '134.177.0.178'}
headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"

r = requests.post(url, data=values, headers = headers)
print(r.text)
```

As I checked in Chrome this form has two data sources: f_ip_list & dataSource. I tried both, but still I cannot get the result. I would appreciate any help.

IP used in code is randomly generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only passing one field in the formdata.

```py
URL = "https://northcutt.com/tools/free-seo-tools/multiple-reverse-ip-lookup/"

values = {
    'f_ip_list':'0.0.0.0',
    'dataSource':'free_seo_tools'
}

response = requests.post(url=URL,data=values)
```

OUTPUT:

```js
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: Oh, it was in front of my nose. Thank you